# SQL - Nested Columns possible?

Tags: sql-server

I'm fairly au fait with SQL but there is one thing I'm not sure is possible so I thought I'd give it a go asking another queston on here.

I have the need to return "Countries" as each row, and then have 3 columns for each Country which records an average of percentages from another table. This is fine, I can do this without problem.

The place I am stuck is that, I want the 3 columns per row to be repeated for, let's say, each month. So, effectively, I want the 3 columns to be nested under a higher level column which contains the month name. The layout I need is below (the column "Index" is a calculation of the percentage in the Company1/2 columns)

```
      |         January            |
```

Country|Company 1|Company 2|Index|

Is this even possible?

Comment: SQL Server works with rows and columns, what you seem to be talking about is presentation, which would be done in something like Excel or Reporting Services.

Comment: Only if you want to manage it yourself and it's highly not recommended because it conflicts with how data normalisation and data modelling should function. You're much better off to do it correctly and just change in presentation

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it was desirable to get it done without having to manipulate in excel or anything afterwards but it looks as though that is the only way!

Comment: It's the better way to keep presentation separate from data logic

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this sort of thing with dynamic SQL, just for example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Example (Country varchar(20))

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @prefix nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @startMonth int=3
DECLARE @endMonth int=6

DECLARE @currentMonth int=@startMonth

WHILE @currentMonth<@endMonth
BEGIN
  SET @prefix='Month'+CAST(@currentMonth AS varchar(10))
  SET @sql='ALTER TABLE #Example ADD'
  +'['+@prefix+'_Company1] varchar(20)'
  +',['+@prefix+'_Company2] varchar(20)'
  +',['+@prefix+'_Index] int'
  EXEC (@sql)

  SET @sql='...' -- ... SQL to set values into the prefixed columns based upon your criteria
  EXEC (@sql)

  SET @currentMonth=@currentMonth+1
END

select * from #Example -- The result with 3 columns per month
```

This will add 3 columns for each month, each with a unique prefix from the @currentMonth value

Maybe this technique gives you a basis for a solution?